# Leaflet -- can't change radius on circlemarker on zoom

Tags: javascript, leaflet, mapbox

I'm using [Leaflet](http://leafletjs.com/) to visualize point data and I'm trying to change the radius of circle according to the zoom level.

The more the user is **zoomed in**, the **larger** the radius.

[Work in progress available here.](http://pennybeames.net/maps/globalDams.html)

Here's what I have so far.

The first line sets the initial radius:

```
var damsRadius = 2;
```

Then I have a zoomend event to get the zoom level and then use that zoom level to determine the new radius:

```
map.on('zoomend', function(e) {
    var currentZoom = map.getZoom();
    console.log("Current Zoom" + " " + currentZoom);
    if (currentZoom <= 6) {
        damsRadius = 2;
    } else {
        damsRadius = 6;
    }
    console.log("Dams Radius" + " " + damsRadius);
});
```

I set the radius as part of the style object:

```
function damsStyle(feature) {
    return {
      fillOpacity: 0.8,
      fillColor: getColor(feature.properties.mainuse),
      weight: 1,
      opacity: 1,
      color: '#e0e0e0',
      radius: damsRadius // HERE IS WHERE I SET THE RADIUS
    };
}
```

and then add the whole kit to the map using  `pointToLayer` later on:

```
pointToLayer: function (feature, latlng) {
    return L.circleMarker(latlng, damsStyle(feature));
}
```

Everything works swimmingly according to the console. Zooming in and out shows that the value for `damsRadius` is changing as expected.

The trouble is, though, the **radius** of the points on the map doesn't change. So, somewhere along the way something isn't getting communicated.

I tried the same trick with `L.circle` but it didn't work either. Do I need to use `clearLayers` function and **redraw** every time I change the zoom level?

That seems a bit excessive.

Advice?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to **reset** the style once the `zoom` changes.

Simply add the below line in your `map.on('zoomend')` function

```
timeline.setStyle(damsStyle)
```

so, your function would be like this

```
map.on('zoomend', function(e) {
    var currentZoom = map.getZoom();
    console.log("Current Zoom" + " " + currentZoom);
    if (currentZoom <= 6) {
      damsRadius = 2;
    } else {
    damsRadius = 6;
    }
    console.log("Dams Radius" + " " + damsRadius);
    timeline.setStyle(damsStyle)//add this line to change the style
});
```

**Note:** You might need to change the scope of your `timeline` variable in order to access it in `zoomend` function.

Comment: Ah! I didn't even think of setStyle.

You're right -- initial tests show that I'll have to change the scope. Not enough time to delve in right now, but thanks for pointing me in the right direction!

Comment: I moved the 'zoomend' function with the new setStyle line from outside my AJAX call to inside to solve the scope issue and now it works like a charm.

Comment: One more optimization that could be added. The above function would be running setStyle() on every zoom change, regardless if it was warranted or not. It should only change the style when necessary, and that's when the zoom passes the given threshold. Save the last zoom in a variable, and compare both the zoom and previous zoom to get a much more performant function